# Problem with optirun bumblebee

Tags: nvidia, xorg, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I'm trying to run optirun on my Lenovo G580 with nVidia GeForce 610M on Ubuntu 14.04. Getting the following error

```
$ optirun glxgears
[   98.457967] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) intel(0): [drm] failed to set drm interface version: Permission denied [13].
[   98.458061] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

My .conf file: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7278805/

Please help asap,thanks

EDIT: I also tried to run nvidia-settings to enable the nVidia gpu,but it does not work and gives a blank error/dialog box:

[image]

Comment: I also tried solutions given [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2036010) and [here](http://mylinuxexplore.blogspot.in/2014/03/solved-nvidia-cant-access-secondary-gpu.html) in vain.

Comment: All other solutions on the internet seem to address concerns where the error is [XORG] (EE) NVIDIA(0)..

Comment: Try using virtualgl instead of primus.

Comment: @renatov can you tell me a complete procedure to do that? I don't know what is virtualgl,complete noob here.

Comment: I encountered this problem as well and I found this question before finding the correct answer. So for future reference. This is bug 580 of the bumblebee project and the fix is described here: https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/580

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently found a crude solution to this: purging all nvidia* related files using:

```
    sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
    sudo apt-get purge bumblebee*
    sudo apt-get update
```

And then using "Additional Drivers" from Dash, I selected "Using Nvidia binary driver- version 331.38 from nvidia-331(proprietary,tested) and selected "Apply Changes" to confirm.

A short download later, I could run glxgears with 4 times the framerate I ever got with the Intel HD 3000.

Although this is not a solution to my problem, still it enables me to use my Nvidia GPU,so I think i'll use this for now till I get a satisfactory solution to bumblebee.

Answer (score 0):

Try using nvidia-prime. Check [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/458389/are-optimus-notebooks-working-properly-on-ubuntu-14-04/458429?noredirect=1#comment603684_458429) and follow Louis Matthijssen instructions. I have a Dell Inspiron 14R 5421 with GeForce 730M on Ubuntu 14.04 and everything is working just fine. I played Dota 2 in maximum video settings, everything working like a charm.